# Panda query condition in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I have a trip data with datetime info and user id for each trip. I am trying to create a new column called "next_trip" with the datetime info of that user's next trip.

Here's a data sample (panda dataframe), named All_Data:

```
HoraDTRetirada        idpass                                                     

2016-02-17 15:36:00  39579449489     
2016-02-24 19:13:00  48663837456     
2016-02-26 09:20:00  72986744521     
2016-02-28 12:11:00  85935174645     
2016-02-28 14:55:00  11533148958
```

The way I thought to do this was first sort the entries by datetime, then for each different user trip, find his next trip by filtering (through a query) by user id (idpass). The reason why I reindex is because I was getting a duplicate value error.
And here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
unique_ids = All_Data['idpass'].unique()
temp = All_Data.sort_values('HoraDTRetirada')
temp['index'] = np.arange(len(temp))
temp = temp.set_index('index')

for row in unique_ids:
    temp["next_trip"]=temp.query('idpass == "%s"' % row)["HoraDTRetirada"].shift(-1)
```

My problem is related to the for loop. When I do this manually and pick a value of idpass to use in the query condition, I get correct entries for that user's trips as a new column (next_trip), but trying to use the for loop to get this done for all idpass values, I only get NaTs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
#data changed for no NaT output - need size of each group 2 or more
print (All_Data)
        HoraDTRetirada       idpass
0  2016-02-17 15:36:00  39579449489
1  2016-02-24 19:13:00  39579449489
2  2016-02-26 09:20:00  39579449489
3  2016-02-28 12:11:00  85935174645
4  2016-02-28 14:55:00  85935174645


All_Data = All_Data.sort_values('HoraDTRetirada')
All_Data['next_trip'] = All_Data.groupby('idpass')['HoraDTRetirada'].shift(-1)
print (All_Data)
        HoraDTRetirada       idpass            next_trip
0  2016-02-17 15:36:00  39579449489  2016-02-24 19:13:00
1  2016-02-24 19:13:00  39579449489  2016-02-26 09:20:00
2  2016-02-26 09:20:00  39579449489                  NaN
3  2016-02-28 12:11:00  85935174645  2016-02-28 14:55:00
4  2016-02-28 14:55:00  85935174645                  NaN
```

Comment: I am trying to apply the same idea to generate a column with the number of same_day_trips by each user(idpass), with the following code but it doesn't work: `All_Data['same_day_trips']=All_Data.groupby(['idpass','day','month']).value_counts()` . I get this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Comment: It seems you need size -`All_Data1=All_Data.groupby(['idpass','day',‌​'month']).size()` But ifneed new column need `All_Data['same_day_trips']=All_Data.groupby(['idpass','day',‌​'month'])['idpass'].transform('size')`